# Identify if a token contract was deployed using Create2

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment, create2

Is there a way to analyze a token contract and determine if it was created using Create2?

Comment: You can do a debug trace on the transaction that deployed the contract. However it is advanced technique and you need deep EVM insight to know how to do it.

Comment: this is something I'd be willing to provide compensation for if someone could help me look at 2 addresses

Answer (score 4):

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");

(async () => {

  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("YOUR_PROVIDER");

  const response = await provider.send("debug_traceTransaction", ["TX_HASH",{"tracer": "callTracer"},]);
  
  const calls = response.calls || [];
  const hasMatchingObject = calls.some(item => {
    return item.type === "CREATE2" && item.to === "CONTRACT_ADDRESS";
  });
  hasMatchingObject ? console.log("Create2") : console.log("No create2");

})();
```

This does what you need (it logs "create2" if the contract at  CONTRACT_ADDRESS was created using create2 and "no create2" otherwise).

Here's how to run it (skip if you know)

install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en).

create a new folder
In this folder on a terminal window, run `npm init` (skip through everything its gonna ask you), then `npm install ethers`.

Still in this folder, create a .js file (name it as you want), paste this in it, (make sure to replace `YOUR_PROVIDER`, `TX_HASH` and `CONTRACT_ADDRESS` with the relevant values), then save it.

In your terminal window from earlier, run `node yourfilename.js`
It's  gonna return what i previously said.

My 0x address is in my bio if you wanna send something, but you don't have to, this took me 5 minutes and a google search.

---

EDIT (see comments) : On an etherscan contract page (etherscan.io/address/... not etherscan.io/token/..., those only show stats about a token), there is a 'contract creator', field. You can see the contract deployment transaction from here. If the transactions `to` field displays " ['address' Created], (like [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4b37d2f343608457ca3322accdab2811c707acf3eb07a40dd8d9567093ea5b82)) that means the contract was deployed directly from an EoA, and that it wasnt using create2. If the `to` field is just a contract address, without any mention of a contract creation (like [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1888125e44400ae7d8bb074f65e88d6a3f060f7ccc6c38a6f4bc730c98f0ed33)), that means the contract was deployed  by another contract, in that case  go to the 'Internal Txns' tab, if you see a line with `create2_X_X_X` there, that means create2 was used. If you see `create_X_X_X`, that means it wasnt.

Comment: ( alternatively if you don't wanna install anything you can try and run the code in an online sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/ )

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for taking the time to share this. I'm getting sort of a strange error on my end:

  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'debug_traceTransaction',
  info: {
    error: {
      code: -32601,
      message: 'The method debug_traceTransaction does not exist/is not available'
    },
    payload: {
      method: 'debug_traceTransaction',
      params: [
        '0x4b37d2f343608457ca3322accdab2811c707acf3eb07a40dd8d9567093ea5b82',
        { tracer: 'callTracer' }
      ],
      id: 2,
      jsonrpc: '2.0'
    }
  }

But will keep troubleshooting

Comment: I think this is because I don't have a paid plan on Infura or anywhere else, so I am out of luck. thank you anyway!

Comment: That's probably why yeah. If you're on ETH mainnet use a demo endpoint. https://docs-demo.quiknode.pro/ works . (obviously it will only work a few times, so if you need to do that often you'll need a paid plan somewhere)

Comment: (or run a light node)

Comment: If you can tell me if the UNI token was created using Create2, I will send you a donation :) 

https://etherscan.io/token/0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984

Comment: It wasnt, it was created through a regular transaction directly by a wallet ( 0x41653c7d61609D856f29355E404F310Ec4142Cfb ). Only other contracts can create a contract with create2. I answered by providing code since this is a dev-focused forum and i was under the impression you were looking for an automated method of telling if a contract was created with create2. I'll edit my answer with how you can do it with etherscan

Comment: @ether_explorer11111 ^